# show service status with updated images

Tags: nsis

At the end of our installer we want to start several services that were installed in a previous step and show their status.
Kinda like a bunch of traffic lights that turn from red to green if the according service is running.

Is that even possible to show the actual status of the services as they are started?
This should be on a single screen that updates itself.

Comment: Should this screen block clicking Next until all services are started? How many services? 3? 5? >10?

Comment: Blocking "Next" could be an option but no a must-have. There are about 16 Services.

Answer (score 1):

16 services is just about the limit you can fit on one page I imagine but I'm only using two in this example:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include Win\COM.nsh
!define /IfNDef VT_BOOL 11
!define /IfNDef CLSID_Shell {13709620-C279-11CE-A49E-444553540000}
!ifndef IID_IShellDispatch2
!define IID_IShellDispatch2 {A4C6892C-3BA9-11d2-9DEA-00C04FB16162}
${NSISCOMIFACEDECL} IShellDispatch2 IsServiceRunning 36 (w,p)i
!endif

Function IsServiceRunning ; This should work on Win2000+, for anything older you must call EnumServicesStatus directly
Exch $1
Push $0
!insertmacro ComHlpr_CreateInProcInstance ${CLSID_Shell} ${IID_IShellDispatch2} r0 ""
${If} $0 P<> 0
    Push $1
    ${IShellDispatch2::IsServiceRunning} $0 '(s,@r1)'
    ${IUnknown::Release} $0 ""
    System::Call '*$1(&i2.r0,&i6,&i2.r1)' ; $1 will be <> 0 if the service is running
    ${IfThen} $0 <> ${VT_BOOL} ${|} StrCpy $1 0 ${|} ; Not a VT_BOOL, assume we failed
${Else}
    StrCpy $1 0
${EndIf}
Pop $0
Exch $1
FunctionEnd


!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include WinMessages.nsh

Page InstFiles
Page Custom mySvcPage

Section
; Install and start services here
SectionEnd


!macro UpdateServiceIcon control ico icopath size
System::Call 'USER32::LoadImage(p0, ts, i ${IMAGE_ICON}, i${size}, i${size}, i${LR_LOADFROMFILE})p.s' "${icopath}"
Pop ${ico}
Push ${ico}
SendMessage ${control} ${STM_SETIMAGE} ${IMAGE_ICON} ${ico} ${ico}
${NSD_FreeIcon} ${ico} ; Free the old icon
Pop ${ico}
!macroend

Var svc1
Var svc1ico
Var svc2
Var svc2ico
Var count

Function mySvcPage
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

File "/oname=$PluginsDir\SvcW.ico" "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Icons\llama-grey.ico"
File "/oname=$PluginsDir\SvcR.ico" "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Icons\llama-blue.ico"
!macro UpdateServiceIconFromServiceState svcname control ico size
Push "${svcname}"
Call IsServiceRunning
Pop $0
${If} $0 <> 0
    StrCpy $0 "$PluginsDir\SvcR.ico"
    IntOp $count $count + 1
${Else}
    StrCpy $0 "$PluginsDir\SvcW.ico"
${EndIf}
!insertmacro UpdateServiceIcon ${control} ${ico} $0 ${size}
!macroend

${NSD_CreateIcon}  10u 10u 15u 15u ""
Pop $svc1
${NSD_CreateLabel} 25u 10u 40u 10u "W32Time"
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateIcon}  10u 25u 15u 15u ""
Pop $svc2
${NSD_CreateLabel} 25u 25u 40u 10u "Themes"
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateTimer} UpdateServicesStatus 1000
Call UpdateServicesStatus
nsDialogs::Show
${NSD_KillTimer} UpdateServicesStatus
${NSD_FreeIcon} $svc1ico
${NSD_FreeIcon} $svc2ico
FunctionEnd

Function UpdateServicesStatus
StrCpy $count 0
!insertmacro UpdateServiceIconFromServiceState "W32Time" $svc1 $svc1ico 16
!insertmacro UpdateServiceIconFromServiceState "Themes" $svc2 $svc2ico 16
GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 1 ; Next/Close button
${If} $count >= 2
    EnableWindow $0 1
${Else}
    EnableWindow $0 0
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

If the number of services is not known at compile-time or if there are too many to fit on a page then you have to use a [ListView control](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Header_file_for_Listview) instead to display the service status.